# How can I use html forms to create a page or html code when submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For example, I have a few forms on a page, when they are all filled then submitted, I want the information to be converted into html so I can paste it into the proper page, or it create a page on its own. Wordpress and some other websites use things similar to this, but I am not that advanced. I'm alright with html and css, but not so much the javascript and php that may be required.

I'd want it to look something like this:

```
<form action="something.php">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  Favorite Color:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Favorite Color">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br><br>
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The added code is something similar to what I would be looking for. I was short on time when making that. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

A form tag in html will send the input values you have thought the method you've used

for example:

```html
<form action="something.php" method="post">
```

this form will redirect you to something.php after submitting it and you can retrieve the values of your inputs thought $_POST
for example if you have

```html
 <input type="text" name="test">
```

then you can retrieve it and use it in `something.php` with the `$_POST['test']`.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to do with php.
You read in the values from the form (GET or POST, depending on which you use) and build an HTML site out of it.
If you post your form and how you want the HTML-Site to be built, I can show you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from what you have posted.

1. Create a target page in which the User Input can be posted.
2. Create a form such as `<form method = "Post" Action = "Page.php"></form>`
3. In your target page use the `$_POST['VariableName'];` to get the value from the input types.
4. Use echo to print out the values.

Comment: I fixed your answer. Do read up on superglobals http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php `$_Post` will fail as per your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34053727/1 where you didn't highlight code with ticks `\``. The syntax is `$_POST` in uppercase and is extremely important.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write an HTML page with a form that can submit the data to your server for processing. Mozilla provides a good starter page for working with HTML form submission:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

They have an example on that page about receiving form data for processing. You would need to process the received data to your preferred format, then write it to an appropriate HTML file. One PHP method you could use to achieve this is file_put_contents, which writes a string to a file. Find the PHP documentation here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php.

However, your question is quite vague. If you could post more details, or a specific problem that you're having, you could get a more specific answer. I think these references can get you started if you're just looking for general guidance.